# NewRelic - what is it good for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, newrelic

We want to monitor events in our application and send the data to a monitoring server like NewRelic...  We then want to be able to configure alerts based on this custom data.  For example, if an event doesn't happen for 10 minutes we want an alert.  Does anyone know if NewRelic is the right tool for task?  Similarly, if we have a cronjob that fails, we want an alert about it and we want to be able to see the log file.  Is NewRelic equipped for this use case as well?

We actually prefer to work with NodeJS and that ecosystem, so if you know of a monitoring server that does alerting and everything with a javascript scripting language built in... that would probably be ideal for us.

Comment: Good question but this is can be asked on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: I'm not at all affiliated with NewRelic.

To answer your question: yes -- NewRelic can do the things you mentioned above, but it's probably not the best tool for the job. If you want to have really good exception alerts, etc., you'll probably be better off using a tool like Sentry (https://getsentry.com/welcome/).

What NewRelic really excels at, however, is helping you debug issues while you're building your application -- and then, helping you fix performance problems when your application is in production. I've been using NewRelic for nearly 4 years now, and it's been a super awesome part of my toolset.

Here's why I like it:

- It's ridiculously easy to install. Usually a single line of code.
- It collects all sorts of metrics from your application as it's running: how many requests you're doing, what each request is doing, etc.
- It shows you at a granular level exactly what is happening on each request: how much time you spent connecting to the database, making a query, processing some function, etc. VERY USEFUL for fixing performance problems.
- It provides really great alerting for performance issues -- you can get alerts if your overall performance drops below a percentage, of if you've suddenly started generating a lot of 500 responses.
- It's UI is killer -- really easy to work with, and filled with stats / useful data.

Over the past few years it's been the only tool I use in every single project I start.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the info.  I appreciate hearing about a product from someone who has experience using it.